# Insert an array in a jquery String

Tags: jquery, arrays

Hi i have a question about arrays and string in jquery

```
var fonts = ["<option>Arial</option>","<option>Arial Black</option>","<option>Calibri</option>","<option>Courier New</option>","<option>Comic Sans MS</option>","<option>Garamond</option>","<option>Georgia</option>","<option>Impact</option>","<option>Tahoma</option>","<option>Palatino</option>","<option>Times New Roman</option>","<option>Tahoma</option>","<option>Verdana</option>"];

function addselection(){ var string = "<select>fonts</select>";
 $('#id').append(string);}
```

i dont have any idea how it will work.. i just need suggestions or answer thank you

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: unclear? it's very clear what he wants: he wants to append each position of the array (that is an `option` element) to a `select`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array, so you need to iterate over all positions of this array and append each one. The simplest way is by using a `for` loop and then, in each iteration, append the option, like below.

There's also another ways to do that, like you will see in others answers, but I think (my opinion), for begginers (if you are), this is best choice)

```js
var fonts = ["<option>Arial</option>","<option>Arial Black</option>","<option>Calibri</option>","<option>Courier New</option>","<option>Comic Sans MS</option>","<option>Garamond</option>","<option>Georgia</option>","<option>Impact</option>","<option>Tahoma</option>","<option>Palatino</option>","<option>Times New Roman</option>","<option>Tahoma</option>","<option>Verdana</option>"];

function addselection(){
  for (var i =0; i < fonts.length; i++){
    var myOption = fonts[i];
    $('#id').append(myOption);
  }
}
 
 addselection();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='id'></select>
```

Comment: thank you for this one it helped alot

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

Loop fonts array and append to select

```js
var fonts = ["<option>Arial</option>","<option>Arial Black</option>","<option>Calibri</option>","<option>Courier New</option>","<option>Comic Sans MS</option>","<option>Garamond</option>","<option>Georgia</option>","<option>Impact</option>","<option>Tahoma</option>","<option>Palatino</option>","<option>Times New Roman</option>","<option>Tahoma</option>","<option>Verdana</option>"];

function addselection(){ 
  var string = "<select>fonts</select>";
 $('#id').append(string);
  $.each(fonts, function(key, value) {   
     $('select')
         .append($(value)); 
});
}

addselection();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="id"></div>
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aYjmvV